# Difference between a socket and a port

Tags: networking, sockets, networks

Could someone please explain quite clearly the difference between a port and a socket. I know that a port serves as a door into the network for an application 
process and that the application process uses a socket connection to the given port number to handle network communication but when you have multiple processes listening on a single port number, I am finding it difficult to understand the difference between the socket and the port and how they all fit together.

Comment: Port is a physical address, while socket is an object.

Comment: If a packet hits a pocket on a socket on a port...

Comment: Can you elaborate on "when you have multiple processes listening on a single port number"?  That seems like a misconception to me.  I thought the whole idea of port numbers was to uniquely identify a particlar process running on a machine at a specific IP address.  If I'm equally misguided about that, I hope some of the answers (or other comments) will correct me.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

**S** is a server program: let's say it's an HTTP server, so it'll use the well-known port number for [HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230.txt), which is 80. I run it on a host with IP address `10.0.0.4`, so it will listen for connections on `10.0.0.4:80` (because that's where everyone will expect to find it).

Inside **S**, I'm going to create a [socket](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/socket.html) and [bind](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/bind.html) it to that address: now, the OS knows that connections coming into `10.0.0.4:80` should be routed to my **S** process via that particular socket.

- netstat output once socket is bound:

  ```
  $ netstat --tcp -lan
  Active Internet connections (servers and established)
  Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address            State
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                  LISTEN
  ```

  NB. the local address is all zeroes because **S** doesn't care how its clients reach it

Once **S** has this socket bound, it will [accept](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/accept.html) connections - each time a new client connects, `accept` returns a *new* socket, which is specific to that client

- netstat output once a connection is accepted:

  ```
  $ netstat --tcp -lan
  Active Internet connections (servers and established)
  Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address            State
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                  LISTEN
  tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:80                 10.0.0.5:55715             ESTABLISHED
  ```

  - `10.0.0.4:80` represents **S**'s end of the connection, and is associated with the socket returned by `accept`
  - `10.0.0.5:55715` is the client's end of the connection, and is associated with the socket the client passed to [connect](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/connect.html). The client's port isn't used for anything except routing packets on this TCP connection to the right process: it's assigned randomly by the client's kernel from the ephemeral port range.

Now, **S** can happily go on accepting more client connections ... each one will get its own socket, each socket will be associated with a unique TCP connection, and each connection will have a unique remote address. **S** will track client state (if there is any) by associating it with the socket.

So, roughly:

- the IP address is for routing between hosts on the network
- the port is for routing to the correct socket on the host

  - I nearly said *correct process*, but it's actually possible to have multiple (usually child) processes all accepting on the same socket ...
  - however, each time one of the concurrent `accept` calls returns, it does so in only *one* process, each incoming connection's socket is unique to one instance of the server
- the socket is the object a process uses to talk to the OS about a particular connection, much like a file descriptor

  - as mentioned in comments, there are plenty of other uses for sockets that don't use ports at all: for example [socketpair](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/socketpair.html) creates a pair of sockets connected together that have *no* addressing scheme at all - the only way to use that pipe is by being the process which called `socketpair`, being a child of that process and inheriting one, or being explicitly passed one of the sockets from that process

Comment: @Useless It's worth mentioning sockets do *not* need to be IP based as the answer indicates. It's not exactly relevant to the OP but an explanation of the [socket families](http://linux.die.net/man/2/socket) would help round out this answer.

Comment: Good point - I was already getting concerned about scope creep when I started writing about multi-process servers. Feel free to edit it in, and if you don't, I'll get round to it at some point ...

Comment: this is not useless at all

Comment: I try to understand socket in electronics, a server bind a socket to a port number is like put a socket on a wall waiting for some electronical devices to plugin for charging battery. But when accepted, a new socket is returned? Why? A new socket is put one the wall? Please help me make sense out of it by some analogy.

Comment: The problem here is that your analogy is wrong. Forget what a socket means in the physical world - it's not a metaphor for something else, just a technical term for a specific technical software concept. It isn't even strongly related to physical network ports or sockets - you just have to understand it, in this domain, as a concept on its own terms.

Comment: @AaronShen, as already mentioned, the analogy does not work out very well. But to shortly address the "Why?": Because else the socket would be occupied by the first client connecting and no one else could connect until the connection to this first client is closed. In your analogy you have to first unplug the first device before you can plug a second device. In software we have the luxury to magically create a new socket for each connection to allow multiple clients to connect simultaneously. We cannot do this in the real world, this is where the analogy breaks.

Answer (score 54):

Think of your machine as an apartment building:

- A port is an apartment number.
- A socket is the door of an apartment.
- An IP address is the street address of the building.

Comment: I like this analogy although now I'm thinking of being inside that apartment looking at an endless corridor with lots of doors. I cannot get out. I cannot get out! :)

Comment: @Caleb `A socket is the door of an apartment.` But couldn't there be numerous sockets open at one port?

Comment: @suhail Sometimes an apartment has more than one door. They all have the same apartment number, but they're different doors.

Comment: This is an awesome analogy that clearly illustrates the *scope* of each layer of *abstraction*.

You’re attempting to route *traffic* to a specific *process* running on a specific *computer* “somewhere” in the world . A delivery  driver cannot make good on his/her *attempt* at *success* without an accurate *location* and *recipient* (this is where we get into *messaging*, *modeling*, and delivery *protocols*). Thanks much!  

Comment: @Caleb I agree with @suhail-gupta in that `the door` is implicitly talking about a unique door, while `a door` or `any of the doors` allow multiple doors, implicitly and explicitly, respectively.

Answer (score 48):

A port is part of the address in the TCP and UDP protocols. It is used to help the OS identify which application should get the data that is received. An OS has to support ports to support TCP and UDP because ports are an intrinsic part of TCP and UDP.

A socket is part of the interface the OS presents to applications to allow them to send and receive network data. Most socket implementations support many protocols beyond TCP and UDP, some of which have no concept of ports. An OS does not have to support sockets to support TCP or UDP; it could provide a different interface for applications to use. A socket is simply one way of sending and receiving data on a specific port.

Comment: A socket is essentially a 4 tuple made up of: Source IP:Port-Dest IP:Port.

Comment: you mean that port exists only in TCP and UDP protocols??? What about http and other protocols?

Comment: HTTP is an application layer protocol that runs on top of transport layer protocols like TCP or UDP. It doesn't have its own concept of ports, it inherits them from the underlying transport layer protocol.

Comment: Would you add some reference in your answer?

Answer (score 8):

A computer has an IP address that identifies it as a separate entity on the network.  We add an additional number to that to allow us to differentiate between connections to that computer.  This is the port number.  On the OS side of the connection you need buffers, connection state, etc.  This logical object is the socket.

Answer (score 0):

A socket is a communication path to a port. When you want your program to communicate over the network, you have given it a way of addressing the port and this is done by creating a socket and attaching it to the port.
Basically, socket = IP + ports Sockets provide access to the port+ip

Answer (score -1):

An IP address identifies the device ie the address to the particular device, when you reached the machine using IP now port defines to which process in that machine to communicate.

So for actual communication to take place you need both port+IP which is called socket.